# How do I know when I've had the last call to ChildEventListener.onChildAdded(), for now?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Supposing I have a Firebase Database location, `/foo`, which has five children under it right now. I expect that more children will be added over the next few minutes. I have a child event listener on this database reference and I'm getting five calls back to `onChildAdded()` immediately when I add the listener as expected.

I'm going to keep my listener around as long as my Android app is running to handle new children, but for now, say, at app startup, I'm really interested in when I've got the last of the existing five children.

How do I do this?

I don't want to add a `ValueEventListener` as well as the `ChildEventListener`, since that just doubles up on data transfer. It feels like there should be a `Task` somewhere in the API that I can get a callback from when complete, but I can't find it.

Comment: Maybe use [this?](https://www.firebase.com/docs/java-api/javadoc/com/firebase/client/DataSnapshot.html#getChildrenCount--) Then keep handy a counter each time a child is added.

Comment: "... since that just doubles up on data transfer." Are you sure of that?

Answer (score 1):

I've ended up using a delayed handler for now, although I'll gladly accept a better answer.

```
class PositionListener implements ChildEventListener {

    private MyService service;

    private final Handler lastChildHandler = new Handler();

    private final Runnable lastChildRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            service.onModelChanged();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildName) {
        // Omitted: Handle this child.

        // Push the time at which we let the service know the model has
        // changed and redraw the view out another 20ms. This means 
        // lastChildRunnable.run() will never actually run until after
        // the last child for a while.
        lastChildHandler.removeCallbacks(lastChildRunnable);
        lastChildHandler.postDelayed(lastChildRunnable, 20);
    }

    // Omitted: other overrides

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I went to the same problems too. And for now here is my solution:

I put `addChildEventListener` and `addValueEventListener` on the same `DatabaseReference`. I read some reference (I forgot, perhaps someone can comment it) says that `onDataChange` of `addValueEventListener` will be called after all of `addChildEventListener` event have been finished.

Not the best solution, I know, but can be another option.